# Does Google still have benchmarking report?

Tags: analytics

I have been looking for Google benchmarking reports for a while, still cannot find it.

Is it still available?

Answer (score 4):

The in-application report was removed last year, and [was replaced with an e-mail newsletter](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/03/evolution-of-analytics-benchmarking.html) sent directly to you (which is no longer being sent since June 2012). You <del>have</del> had to [allow data sharing](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1009704) in your account settings to enable it.

Currently, Google is exploring new ways to enable this feature in the future.

Comment: Answer [now out of date](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/72048/2096).

Answer (score 0):

This feature was [re-introduced in September 2014](https://econsultancy.com/blog/65422-google-analytics-benchmarking-is-back-here-s-what-you-need-to-know#i.29593xmflf5yv7) after it was discontinued back in 2011.

[Google's official blog post](http://analytics.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/new-benchmarking-reports-help-twiddy.html) on the re-introduction explains where to find it:

> Benchmarking reports can be found in the “Audience” section of the reporting interface [...] If you want to join in, simply check the “Share anonymously with Google and others” box in the Account Settings tab of your account admin page.

[image: Check the “Share anonymously with Google and others” box to enable to benchmarking tool.]